# passwd doesn't work: Authentication token manipulation error

Tags: ubuntu, security, login, passwd

I have an strange problem...
I cannot login to my Ubuntu using my own private key. Fortunately I have a  password and it works but I cannot change my password. I can su user to root. See the following command outputs:

```
root@myhost:/# passwd myuser
Enter new UNIX password: 
Retype new UNIX password:
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

Then I tried this:

```
root@myhost:/# pwconv
pwconv: cannot open /etc/passwd
```

There aren't any .lock files in /etc but

```
/etc/group 
/etc/group-
/etc/gshadow
/etc/gshadow-
/etc/shadow
/etc/shadow-
/etc/passwd
/etc/passwd-
```

are exist.

What can I do?

Comment: Someone asked the same question some years ago on Ask Ubuntu.

https://askubuntu.com/a/57622/67665

Can you check if the accepted solution there applies to you?

Comment: I had checked it before but it did not help me, @pkhamre

Comment: So you are saying that an entry for `myuser` exists in both `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`? 

`sudo grep myuser /etc/passwd` and `sudo grep myuser /etc/shadow`

Comment: yes, I confirm @pkhamre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something or someone has set an immutable flag for `/etc/passwd` and/or `/etc/shadow` file.

Check with `lsattr /etc/passwd /etc/shadow` and if the result contains `i` in response, remove the immutable flag with `chattr -i /etc/passwd /etc/shadow`.

Comment: is this a default attribute in Ubuntu 12.04? I cannot understand how it should be happened ?

Comment: Not that I know of. Interesting.

Comment: it is not a complete answer to my problem. would you explain about changing file permissions and restoring default attributes after changing passwords, please?

Answer (score 1):

This may be related to incorrect permissions set to /usr/bin/passwd.
Try to set the permissions to 4755 using the command:

```
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/passwd
```

Which means: User can read, write and execute, group and others can read and execute, and set UID bit.

Comment: so I have 2 questions: 1st) I didn't changed this before. why this should be happened. changing the default permissions isn't unsafe? 2nd) I cannot change the permissions. this error occurs: `chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/shadow': Operation not permitted`

Comment: 1st question) It is unsafe, but 4755 is the default permission, according to my fresh xenial install. 2nd question) You must type 'sudo' before administrative applications. I edited the answer to include the sudo command.

Comment: I'm not so newbie :)  if you check the question again you can see that I changed to root user. so there is no need to sudo